# What is the canonical way to get text from RichText field with Archetypes

Tags: plone, archetypes

With `Dexterity` content types, the canonical way is to use the transformer:

```py
from plone.app.textfield.interfaces import ITransformer
from plone.app.textfield.value import IRichTextValue


def get_text_field(obj):
    """Get text field in object on Dexterity."""
    transformer = ITransformer(obj)
    text = ''
    if IRichTextValue.providedBy(obj.text):  # Dexterity
        text = transformer(obj.text, 'text/plain')
    return text
```

But I can't find the canonical way to do it with `Archetypes`, the transformer didn't work with the `raw` html, just with `RichTextValue` object.

My approach now is to use `lxml.html` to convert html into text, but I don't know if it works like it should be:

```py
def get_text_field(obj):
    """Get text field in object on both, Archetypes and Dexterity."""
    text = ''
    try:
        raw = obj.getText()  # Archetypes
        if raw != '':
            from lxml import html
            el = html.fromstring(raw)
            text = el.text_content()
    except AttributeError:
        from plone.app.textfield.value import IRichTextValue
        if IRichTextValue.providedBy(obj.text):  # Dexterity
            from plone.app.textfield.interfaces import ITransformer
            transformer = ITransformer(obj)
            text = transformer(obj.text, 'text/plain')
    return text
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Archetypes the regular getter does this for you.

So if you call `getText` on a certain AT type which has a text field, you got the transformed values back: Check https://github.com/plone/Products.Archetypes/blob/e9ad0f4e76544b7890835ca93d25adeca4fc064f/Products/Archetypes/Field.py#L1564

It uses the mimetype specified on the field.

If the output type is `text/html` and you want `text/plain`.

You can get by calling the field getter with the mimetype parameter:

```
obj.getField('text').get(obj, mimetype='text/plain')
```

Further:
`obj.getRawText` returns the actual content, like `obj.text.raw` on a DX content with a RichTextValue.

And you may check if the content provides `IBaseObject` instead of catch `AttributeError`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Mathias